# Fix MySQL UTF-8 Character problems

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I've browsed many similar questions and have not found a solution.  I have a large database that was created from HTML pages (which contained bad characters to begin with).

So I'm seeing a lot of things like this in my database:

```
â?¦
á¹£
Ä?
```

---

```
sÄ?mainÅ should be sēmainō

â??“ should be —

yaá¹£ar should be yaṣar

Ä?n should be ēn

psÄ?laphaÅ should be psēlaphaō

anaggellÅ should be Anaggellō
```

And many, many others.  I have set my table to utf8_general_ci, but it seems like these characters are now "hard coded", and any amount of messing with the character set will make no difference.  Maybe I'm wrong?

What is the most viable way to fix this?  I figured running a bunch of find-replaces would work.  And it does, but I'm realizing there a MANY different broken characters.

It is mostly english but with some Greek and Hebrew words.

Comment: What language is your text in?

Comment: English but there is some Greek and Hebrew. (This is a Bible Commentary)

Comment: Can you post a sample word that is in the wrong encoding and its equivalent in the right encoding, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoding seems to be too broken that it would be very difficult if not impossible to convert it from one encoding to another in a one-way fashion. A simple nested find and replace would probably do the job much faster:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `table`.`string` = SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`table`.`string`, 'á¹£', 'ṣ'), 'â??“', '—'), 'Ä?', 'ē'), 'Å', 'ō')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you set utf8_general_ci then i think your problem is not with mysql it seems like problem in only in render data did you try

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Didn't make any difference at all.  Like I said, the wrong characters appear to be encoded into the text as if they belong there that way.